# I have not managed to get only the value with the true object of the nested array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, react-native

I have the following json where I determine what questions and answers will be

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "apartado": "QUEST 1",
        "answers": [
            {
                "options": 1,
                "right_ans": "yes"
            },
            {
                "options": 2,
                "right_ans": "no"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "apartado": "QUEST 2",
        "answers": [
            {
                "options": 1,
                "right_ans": "yes"
            },
            {
                "options": 2,
                "right_ans": "no"
            }
        ]
    }
    
]
```

this is the following code i have

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, View,Text, FlatList , StyleSheet,Image, ActivityIndicator, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
import articulos from './json'

const App = () => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true);
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
  const [resultadosMulta, setResultadosMulta] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {  
    setdata(articulos);
   
  }, [])


  onChangeValue = (itemSelected, indexcharacter) => {

    const nextState =  data.map((list, i) =>
      list.id == indexcharacter+1
        // Key matches, spread existing state and update list items array
        ? {
            ...list,
            answers: list.answers.map(item =>
              item.options === itemSelected.options
                // Item id match, spread existing item and update price
                ? {
                    ...item,
                    checked : !item.checked
                  }
                // No item id match, pass existing item
                : item
            )
          }
        // No key match, pass existing list
        : list
    )
          setdata(nextState)
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.apartado}</Text>
            <FlatList
                  data={item.answers}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <View style={styles.item}>
                      {item.checked}
                      <CheckBox
                      key={item.options}
                      size={40}
                      checked={item.checked}
                      style={styles.ckItem}
                      onPress={()=> onChangeValue(item, index)}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.WrapText}>
                      <Text>{item.right_ans}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                }
                  keyExtractor={item => item.options}
                />
      </View>
    )
  }

  onShowItemSelected = () => {


   const filtered = data.filter(post => {
    return post.answers.some(answers => answers.checked === true)
  });
   
 
console.log(filtered);

  
  }

return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      
      <FlatList 
        style={styles.list}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
  
    <View styles={styles.wrapButton}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onShowItemSelected}>
      <Text>Mostrar el elemento que seleccionados</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>

)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    marginTop:'10%'
  },
  innerText:{
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  list: {
    flex:1,
    padding:10,
    marginBottom:50
  },
  wrapButton:{
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button:{
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  },
  item:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 8,
    padding: 4,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset:{
      width:0, height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.15,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  WrapText:{
    flex:1,
    marginTop: 16,
    marginLeft: 8
  },
  title:{
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },  
  ckItem:{
    marginTop:5
  }
})

export default App;
```

in this next function it is when it executes to obtain what values I select and does a filtering of the array looking for the object checked = true and it does it correctly only that the nested array attracts the 2 responses and not just one that should be in checked = true

```
  onShowItemSelected = () => {
    
    
       const filtered = data.filter(post => {
        return post.answers.some(answers => answers.checked === true)
      });
    
    
    console.log(filtered);
    
    
      }
```

This is the result

```
  Object {
    "answers": Array [
      Object {
        "options": 1,
        "right_ans": "yes",
      },
      Object {
        "checked": true,
        "options": 2,
        "right_ans": "no",
      },
    ],
    "apartado": "QUEST 2",
    "id": 2,
  },
]
```

But the indicated result should be this where it shows only the response in true but I have not managed to filter the nested object

```
  Object {
    "answers": Array [
      Object {
        "checked": true,
        "options": 2,
        "right_ans": "no",
      },
    ],
    "apartado": "QUEST 2",
    "id": 2,
  },
]
```

Comment: When one tries to `filter` the `data` array and retain all `post`s where `post.answers` array has at least `some` element with `checked` as `true` - that is what one gets. Do you need to filter `answers` and retain only those where `checked` is `true`?

Comment: it is correct is to filter if the answer was checked = true, only filter that content and in case 2 is selected, filter both, only that they contain the checked = true

Comment: So, that's your answer. Please `filter` the `answers`. The current logic, `filter` is done on `data`, correct? But, you require to `filter` the `answers` array.

Comment: look this is how he could help me doing a foreach and an if

Answer (score 0):

They give me the values I need, what do you think of this

```
  onShowItemSelected = () => {

   
  let contentAlert = '';

  data.forEach(item=>{
      item.answers.forEach(awns=>{ 
        if(awns.checked === true){
          contentAlert =  contentAlert +'QUEST ID: '+ `${item.id}.`+'ANSWERS ID:'+awns.options+ `\n`;
        }
    });
  });


console.log(contentAlert);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).